# what kind of Gaussian matrix models are these?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, mp.mathematical-physics, random-matrices

In a physics paper I found a very complicated Gaussian matrix model:

$$ Z = \int \frac{d\mu}{(2\pi)^n} \frac{d\nu}{(2\pi)^n}
\frac{
\prod_{i < j}\left[2 \sinh \frac{\mu_i - \mu_j}{2} \right]^2 \prod_{i < j}\left[2 \sinh \frac{\nu_i - \nu_j}{2} \right]^2
}{\prod_{i,j}\left[ 2 \cosh \frac{\mu_i - \nu_j}{2} \right]^2} e^{\frac{ik}{4\pi}\sum (\mu_i^2 - \nu_i^2)}
$$

Such a formula looks vaguely like the formula for Haar measure on the grou of Unitary matrices - whose exact formula I forget.  Let's derive several simplified versions of this measure:

$$ Z = \int \frac{d\mu}{(2\pi)^n} \frac{d\nu}{(2\pi)^n}
e^{\frac{ik}{4\pi}\sum (\mu_i^2 - \nu_i^2)}
$$
One question is how to meaningfully ascribe a value to a Gaussian integral where the variance is a complex number.  And actually $\mu^2 - \nu^2$ could be negative... so this could be like integrating over the maximual torus of a super-matrix model.

$$ Z = \int \frac{d\mu}{(2\pi)^n} \frac{d\nu}{(2\pi)^n}
\frac{
\prod_{i < j}\left[\mu_i - \mu_j \right]^2 \prod_{i < j}\left[\nu_i - \nu_j \right]^2
}{\prod_{i,j}\left[\mu_i - \nu_j \right]^2} 
e^{\frac{ik}{4\pi}\sum (\mu_i^2 - \nu_i^2)}
$$
This could be like Haar measure on the unitary group $SU(N|N)$ except for the Gaussian.  One more variant is if we use $\sin$ instaed of $\sinh$:

$$ Z = \int \frac{d\mu}{(2\pi)^n} \frac{d\nu}{(2\pi)^n}
\frac{
\prod_{i < j}\left[2 \sin \frac{\mu_i - \mu_j}{2} \right]^2 \prod_{i < j}\left[2 \sin \frac{\nu_i - \nu_j}{2} \right]^2
}{\prod_{i,j}\left[ 2 \cos \frac{\mu_i - \nu_j}{2} \right]^2} 
$$
This could be an integral over some matrix-like objects or over a Lie super algebra. Also there is something like the Cauchy-Binet formula.

What are the appropriate Lie Groups for these setups?  In physics these go under various names like Lens Space model or Chern-Simons theory

Comment: Could you link the paper in question?

Comment: **ABJM Theory as a Fermi Gas** https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4066

Comment: This looks like an integral over $\left(\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})\right)^2$ in $KAK$ coordinates.  I don't see why it should converge.

Comment: @LiorSilberman that may very well be integral doesn't converge. that is the integral being discussed in the physics paper.  Often $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, so that $ik$ is purely imaginary.